# pairwise combinations of large number of variables using mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a very large number of variables in a `dataframe` that represent binary outcomes (0, 1). I am trying to create a new dataframe that makes contrasts of each of the variables using an `ifelse()` condition.

Here is a minimal example to replicate what I am trying achieve.

```
# initial dataframe
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(sf1 = sample(0:1,10, replace=T), sf2 = sample(0:1,10, replace=T), sf3 = sample(0:1,10, replace=T))

# get all pairwise combinations of col names
two_way <- combn(colnames(df1), 2, FUN=paste, collapse='&')

# create contrats of col names
dfs<-paste('ifelse(',two_way,',1,0)', sep='') 

dfs
[1] "ifelse(sf1&sf2,1,0)" "ifelse(sf1&sf3,1,0)" "ifelse(sf2&sf3,1,0)"
```

This creates a character vector of the desired `ifelse()` conditions. What I now want to do is get those conditions into a `mutate` function to create a new dataframe with all my contracts. Something like this

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
        mutate(
            data.frame(
               ifelse(sf1&sf2,1,0),
               ifelse(sf1&sf3,1,0),
               ifelse(sf2&sf3,1,0),
               check.names = FALSE
            )
        )

df2
   sf1 sf2 sf3 ifelse(sf1 & sf2, 1, 0) ifelse(sf1 & sf3, 1, 0) ifelse(sf2 & sf3, 1, 0)
1    0   1   0                       0                       0                       0
2    0   0   0                       0                       0                       0
3    0   1   0                       0                       0                       0
4    0   0   1                       0                       0                       0
5    1   0   1                       0                       1                       0
6    1   1   1                       1                       1                       1
7    1   1   1                       1                       1                       1
8    0   1   1                       0                       0                       1
9    0   1   0                       0                       0                       0
10   1   1   0                       1                       0                       0
```

How can I pass the vector of character contrasts `dfs` to the `mutate` function? Is this possible or is there a better way of achieving the desired outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse(sf1&sf2,1,0)` can also be written as `as.integer(sf1&sf2)`.

I'll do this in base R using `combn`. Use `combn` to create combination of column names, for each combination subset the data from the original dataset and return a named list of 1/0 integers which is appended to original dataset using `cbind`.

```
cbind(df1,combn(names(df1), 2, \(x) {
  setNames(
    list(as.integer(df1[[x[1]]] & df1[[x[2]]])), 
   paste0(x, collapse = "_")
  )
}, simplify = FALSE))

#   sf1 sf2 sf3 sf1_sf2 sf1_sf3 sf2_sf3
#1    0   1   0       0       0       0
#2    0   1   1       0       0       1
#3    0   1   0       0       0       0
#4    1   0   0       0       0       0
#5    0   1   0       0       0       0
#6    1   0   0       0       0       0
#7    1   1   1       1       1       1
#8    1   0   1       0       1       0
#9    0   0   0       0       0       0
#10   0   0   1       0       0       0
```

Comment: thank you! How do I read "\(x) {...}" is that the same as (or similar to) "function(x){...}"?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is the same.